# How can I remove the quick white flash when long pressing on a SwiftUI component?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Remove the quick white flash when long pressing on something. How can I do so with SwiftUI and is it even possible?

```
import SwiftUI

struct LycéesRow: View {
    var lycée: Lycée
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            lycée.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .offset(y: -35)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                .offset(y: -35)
            
            lycée.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 355, height: 200)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .offset(x: 5)
                .offset(y: 39.8)
            
        
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                
                Text(lycée.département + ", France")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .opacity(0.5)
                
                Text(lycée.nom)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)

                
                Text(lycée.ville)
                    .font(.system(size: 13, weight: .light, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
            }.offset(y: -30)
            .offset(x: 10)
        }
    }
}
    
struct LycéesRow_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            LycéesRow(lycée: lycées[0])
            LycéesRow(lycée: lycées[1])
        }
    }
}
```

Got this code where it doesn't look code when I long press because we see the image under which is blurred when we don't click (it's an ultraThinMaterial). How can I change it? I attached an image of what appears when we long press.

[image]

I really don't know how I could fix it since I'm not even sure there's an option to.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it with a @gesturestate property :

```
struct LycéesRow: View {
    var lycée: Lycée
    
    @GestureState private var isLongPressing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
            lycée.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .offset(y: -35)
                .opacity(isLongPressing ? 0.8 : 1.0)
            
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                .frame(width: 365, height: 280)
                .background(.ultraThinMaterial, in: RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15))
                .offset(y: -35)
            
            lycée.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .frame(width: 355, height: 200)
                .clipped()
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .offset(x: 5)
                .offset(y: 39.8)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 1) {
                Text(lycée.département + ", France")
                    .font(.system(size: 15, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .opacity(0.5)
                
                Text(lycée.nom)
                    .font(.system(size: 25, weight: .bold, design: .serif))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                
                Text(lycée.ville)
                    .font(.system(size: 14, weight: .medium, design: .default))
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .opacity(0.9)
            }
            .offset(y: -30)
            .offset(x: 12)
        }
        .gesture(
            LongPressGesture()
                .updating($isLongPressing) { value, state, _ in
                    state = value
                }
        )
    }
}
```